# Show that for any bounded set $E$, there is a $G_δ$ set $G$ for which $E \subset G \text{ and } m^\ast(G) = m^\ast(E).$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that for any bounded set $E$, there is a $G_δ$ set $G$ for which $$E \subset G \text{ and } m^\ast(G) = m^\ast(E).$$

Since $E$ is bounded we have that $m^\ast(E) = M < \infty$, where $M \in \Bbb R$. Now by definition of the outer measure we have that $m^\ast(E) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell(I_n) \le m^\ast(E) + \varepsilon$, where the collection $\{I_n\}_n$ covers $E$. It seems that I would somehow need to make $\varepsilon$ depend on $n$ and then define the $G_\delta$ set $G$ as $$G=\bigcap_{k}\left(\bigcup_{n}I_n\right)$$ since this is an $G_\delta$ set because $\bigcup_{n}I_n$ is open. How can I do this?

Also isn't the set $G=\bigcap_{k}\left(\bigcup_{n}I_n\right)$ same as saying $G=\limsup_{n\to \infty} I_n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking $\epsilon =\frac  1k$ we get $m^\ast(E) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell(I_{n,k}) \le m^\ast(E) + \frac  1 k$, where the collection $\{I_{n,k}\}_n$ covers $E$. The set $G$ you have defined is now a $G_{\delta}$ set containing $E$ and $m^\ast (G)\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell(I_{n,k}) \le m^\ast(E) + \frac  1 k$ for each $k$. Hence, $m^\ast (G)\le m^\ast (E)\le m^\ast (G)$

Comment: What is the index $k$ referring to in $I_{n,k}$?